# Changing an existing template's background color in Ember

Tags: css, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a lot of templates in Emberjs, one of them is a `login` template. What I want to do is change the background color of just that one template.

If do this in my stylesheet:

`body{ background-color: grey }`

It changes the background color in whole app.

Here's the template in question:

```
        <div class="container login">   
         <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="login" >
         <form {{action "loginUser" on="submit"}} class="form-signin">
         <h2 class="form-signin-heading heading">Login</h2>
          {{input type="text" value=username class="input-block-level"}}
          {{input type="password" value=password class="input-block-level"}}
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Login</button>
         </form>
        </script>
        </div>
```

So how can I achieve this? Moreover, is there any way I can organize these templates? My `index.html` file is getting too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `didInsertElement` and `willClearRender` to know when the view is inserted or removed, and add the login class in the body:

```
App.LoginView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'login',
    didInsertElement: function() {
        $('body').addClass('login')
    },
    willClearRender: function() {
        $('body').removeClass('login')
    }
});
```

Css:

```
.login { background-color: grey }
```

Comment: The background will need be put in the body tag. But just in the login route. I will update the anwer.